# defineSlot only when div-x is present

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-dfp, google-publisher-tag

Is it possible to dynamically define a `googletag.defineSlot` only when a corresponding `div-x` is present on page? Defining through Google Tag Manager using [this](https://georgegarside.com/blog/google/doubleclick-publishers-google-tag-manager/) method currently. We are getting these errors on different pages where ad unit isn't present:

googletag.defineSlot was called more times than there are DIVs in the DOM associated with ad slots while in Single Request Mode. This will impact impression count

**Define ad slot and push display**

```
<script>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { 
googletag.defineSlot('/101030411/AC-LDB-3', sizesldb, 'div-4')
                 .addService(googletag.pubads());

googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
googletag.enableServices();
});

var adunits = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="div-"]');
for (var i = 0; i < adunits.length; i++) { googletag.cmd.push(function() { 
googletag.display(adunits[i].getAttribute('id')); }); }
</script>
```

**Div on page:**

```
<div style="text-align: center" id='div-x'></div>
```

Intended action is to only defineSlot when a div-x that matches the declared slot is on the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Thing is you are calling the `cmd.push` function inside your loop. Give a try at the following :

```js
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    var adunits = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="div-"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < adunits.length; i++) { 
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
            googletag.display(adunits[i].getAttribute('id')); 
        }); 
    }    
});
```